# Cannot activate MSMQ on Windows 11 (home) ARM

Tags: windows, msmq

I try to activate MSMQ on Windows 11 AMR, but eventhough it says SERVICES ACTIVATED, the check box is OFF when I go to the TURN ON / OFF WINDOWS FEATURES to check...

check the box MSMQ

[image]

The service is confirmed

[image]

But when checking again, the check box is "OFF" again...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The .NET Framework 4.8.1 release [blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-dotnet-framework-481/) by Microsoft mentions about this:

> "(..) MSMQ is not available on Windows 11 for ARM64 client machines".